# How do I remove a strings last 4 characters in bash

Tags: string, bash, printf

I have this code

```
printf '"%s" ' *.tex
```

which prints all files with .tex in the current directory.

Now I want only the file names (so without ".tex") and print them out the same way.
I know there's a method to shorten the string with

```
printf '"%.4s" ' *.tex
```

but that is not what I want.

Comment: If you want to remove `.tex`, that's the last 4 characters, not 3. But don't you just want to remove everything after the last `.`, no matter how long it is?

Comment: Ah yes, 4 characters, that's right. Sure, everything after the dot and including it should do the trick. But how?